# Update: USER ERROR - TYPO !! grunt-contrib-coffee error finding file & writing to destination

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

In my Gruntfile.js I have the coffee task configured as so and one file `script.coffee` exists in the `src/` directory:

```
coffee: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            /* FIX: exapand: true, */
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'src/',
            src: '**/*.coffee',
            dest: 'lib/',
            ext: '.js'
        }]
    }
}
```

When running `grunt coffee` I get the following **error**:

```
Running "coffee:dist" (coffee) task
>> Source file "script.coffee" not found.
>> Destination (lib/) not written because compiled files were empty.
```

The content of the `script.coffee` is just some code to test the coffeescript configuration and compiles perfectly when I run `coffee -c script.coffee` from the command line.

**script.coffee** for the record:

```
# A bubble sort implementation, sorting the given array in-place.
bubble_sort = (list) ->
  for i in [0...list.length]
    for j in [0...list.length - i] when list[j] > list[j + 1]
      [list[j], list[j+1]] = [list[j + 1], list[j]]
  list


# Test the function.
console.log bubble_sort([3, 2, 1]).join(' ') is '1 2 3'
console.log bubble_sort([9, 2, 7, 0, 1]).join(' ') is '0 1 2 7 9'
```

I have other projects elsewhere using this same configuration... I just can;t figure out the issue...

Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `files: [{ exapand: true ... }]`, it should be `expand: true`.